# To view object array particular value in another page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is [my exercise image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc1vw.png)

I am looking for click the eye image to show the particular div array data only.

Please give me a solution using jQuery or javascript to filter the array of objects. I don't have any idea how to do this.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row" id="R1"></div>
<script>
$('documnet').ready(function(){
    var user={data:[
        {'id':1,'name':'Michael', 'mail':'abcd.gmail.com', 'phone':'11101989','image':'im/img1.png'},
        {'id':2,'name':'Mila', 'mail':'abcd.gmail.com', 'phone':'1011989','image':'im/img1.png'},
        {'id':3,'name':'Paul', 'mail':'abcd.gmail.com', 'phone':'10141990','image':'im/img1.png'},
        {'id':4,'name':'Dennis', 'mail':'abcd.gmail.com', 'phone':'11291993','image':'im/img1.png'},
        {'id':5,'name':'Tim', 'mail':'abcd.gmail.com', 'phone':'3121991','image':'im/img1.png'},
        {'id':6,'name':'Erik', 'mail':'abcd.gmail.com', 'phone':'10311995','image':'im/img1.png'}
        ],
    }
    $.each(user.data,function(key,value){
        $('#R1').append(`
            <div class=col-md-3><div class="card">${value.name}</div></div>
            <div class=col-md-3><div class="card">${value.mail}</div></div>
            <div class=col-md-3><div class="card">${value.phone}</div></div>
            <div class=col-md-3><div class="card" onclick=view()>
            <img style="width:20px"  src='${value.image}'></img></div></div>
            `)
    });
});
function view(){
    alert('hai');
}
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'show the particular div array data only'? All data in your array of objects is already being displayed

Comment: no sir i click the picture with the row to show only this user deatails in another page sir .i alter my code sir please check again sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not perfectly clear what you are trying to achieve and you already asked the same question here: [Filter the array jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73630781/filter-the-array-jquery#comment130024056_73630781)

By the way, in case you meant to determine which is the item in the users array corresponding to the clicked row in the table, I'm sharing a demo using a solution to get there somehow.

The point is having the click event handler determine which is the clicked row (by doing `window.event.currentTarget`) and fetching the id corresponding to the user shown on that row.

Such id was included in the row when you are crafting the table using a data attribute that will be retrieved using `el.dataset['id']` and that's enough to intercept the corresponding item in the original array by using `.filter()`.

This is the demo:

```js
var user = {
  data: [
    {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'Michael',
      'mail': 'abcd.gmail.com',
      'phone': '11101989',
      'image': 'im/img1.png'
    },
    {
      'id': 2,
      'name': 'Mila',
      'mail': 'abcd.gmail.com',
      'phone': '1011989',
      'image': 'im/img1.png'
    },
    {
      'id': 3,
      'name': 'Paul',
      'mail': 'abcd.gmail.com',
      'phone': '10141990',
      'image': 'im/img1.png'
    },
    {
      'id': 4,
      'name': 'Dennis',
      'mail': 'abcd.gmail.com',
      'phone': '11291993',
      'image': 'im/img1.png'
    },
    {
      'id': 5,
      'name': 'Tim',
      'mail': 'abcd.gmail.com',
      'phone': '3121991',
      'image': 'im/img1.png'
    },
    {
      'id': 6,
      'name': 'Erik',
      'mail': 'abcd.gmail.com',
      'phone': '10311995',
      'image': 'im/img1.png'
    }
  ],
}

$('document').ready(function() {
  
  $.each(user.data, function(key, value) {
    $('#R1').append(`
      <div class=col-md-3><div class="card">${value.name}</div></div>
      <div class=col-md-3><div class="card">${value.mail}</div></div>
      <div class=col-md-3><div class="card">${value.phone}</div></div>
      <div class=col-md-3>
        <div class="card" onclick="view()">
          <img style="width:20px" data-id="${value.id}" src='${value.image}' />
        </div>
      </div>
    `)
  });
});

function view() {
  const el = window.event.currentTarget;
  const view = el.querySelector('[data-id]');      
  const id = view.dataset['id'];
  const clickedUser = user.data.filter( (item) => item.id == id );
  console.log(clickedUser);
}
```

```css
div.card{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="R1"></div>
```